# Nextgen gallery show thickbox/shutter from link instead of image

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm trying to show the gallery in a thickbox or shutter window from a link.
if i have a gallery [nggallery id=1] i want to have a link "view photos" and when i click on it a thickbox/shutter window should popup.

i have this working for shutter:

```
<div style="display: none;">[nggallery id=1]</div>
<a class="shutterset_set_1" href="/wp-content/gallery/a/dsc_7304mg.jpg">View photos</a>
```

and this working for thickbox:

```
<div style="display: none;">[nggallery id=6]</div>
<a class="thickbox" href="/wp-content/gallery/d/117.jpg" rel="set_6">View photos</a>
```

It opens but the images count is wrong.It counts the gallery images + the images in the page.In this case my gallery has 13 images but the first image(the one in the link) appears twice and then the count is 14 instead of 13.This is really annoying!!

is there a way to solve it?
Is there an alternative to show the gallery via single link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it with jquery.
I replaced all the image thumbs of the gallery with the link text and remove the text for all links except the first:

```
$(".ngg-galleryoverview").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box .ngg-gallery-thumbnail a").html('View photos <span>&#187;</span>');
    $(this).find(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box .ngg-gallery-thumbnail a").addClass('small');
    $(this).find(".ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box:gt(0) .ngg-gallery-thumbnail a").html('');
            });
```

With this script i can use the shortcode normally, just [nggallery id=1] and it works for both thickbox and shutter.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem i had :)